# Chrome Extension: background.js doesn't work after reactivating extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension works good when I install it first time. But when I deactivate it and activate it again my background.js doesn't work. 
background.js have to start work when extension activated. Why it doesn't start work when I reactivate extension?

**background.js**

```
function checkOrder()
{
   //some logic...
   setTimeout(checkOrder,1000);
}

setTimeout(checkOrder,1000);
```

**manifest.json**

```
...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
...
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? PEBCAC?

Comment: I added my code to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working for me with your code,I ain't sure what is missing!

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Time out",
"description":"This demonstrates time out",
"version":"1",
"manifest_version":2,
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
}
}
```

***background.js***

```
function checkOrder()
{
   console.log("Called..");
   setTimeout(checkOrder,1000);
}
setTimeout(checkOrder,1000);
```

What exactly is not working, is the function call not happening?